# Google Play Services not supported

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to develop an application on the [Recon Jet](https://www.reconinstruments.com/products/jet/) and I am running into some issues. I am currently trying to run the Google Mobile Vision sample application called "[FaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples)." After running it on the Jet, I get an error message that says: `FaceTracker relies on Google Play services, which is not supported by your device. Contact the manufacturer for assistance.` Is there a way I can get Play services on the device? I have tried installing it's apk onto the device through ADB to no avail.

The device runs Android 4.2.1 and has a custom launcher so I can't access standard Android apps, although it does run a full fledged Android OS. 
If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: "Is there a way I can get Play services on the device?" -- not legally.

Answer (score 0):

As an example see cyanogen mod google play implementation

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](https://www.androidpit.com/forum/589877/how-to-install-google-play-store-if-it-is-not-pre-installed), this method requires root access.

> Download a couple of APKs, you can usually find the newest bundle in a
>   zip package on [XDA
>   Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2547054):
>
> - Google Play Store (the newest version you can find)
> - Google Services Framework
> - Google Login Service/Account Manager
>
> If you are rooted you can copy them to your root directory to
>   System/App using a root manager like [ES File
>   Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).
>   Then just restart your device.
>
> If this doesn't work first time you might need to change the
>   permissions on the new APKs to match the rest on your device. Use a
>   file explorer like ES for this. Apparently if you're not rooted you
>   can simply install each APK then reboot and it works for some devices.
>
> Reboot and add your Google account in Settings > Accounts > Add
>   account.
>
> Look for the Play Store in your app drawer.

Hope this helps!